# Update() in Laravel does not seem to be working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I'm working with Laravel 5.8 to develop my project and I have this table which shows some data from the DB:

```
@foreach(\App\Shop\ProductDelivery::all() as $delivery)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $delivery->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $delivery->price }}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="{{ route('editFreeDelivery', $delivery->id) }}">Edit</a>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

As you can see there's a link named `Edit` for editing these data, so when someone clicks on that, this method runs:

```
Route::get('product-information-pages/free-deliveries/{productDelivery}/edit', 'ShopInformationPagesAdminController@editFreeDelivery')->name('editFreeDelivery')->middleware('permission:static-page-manage');

public function editFreeDelivery(ProductDelivery $productDelivery)
    {
        return view('admin.shop.deliveries.edit', compact('productDelivery'));
    }
```

I have also added this form for updating the data sent to the `edit.blade.php`:

```
<form action="{{ route('updateProductDelivery', [$productDelivery->id]) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    {{  @method_field('PATCH') }}
    <label for="title" class="control-label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="title-shop" name="name" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" value="{{ old('name' , $productDelivery->name) }}" autofocus>
    <label for="price" class="control-label">Price</label>
    <input type="text" id="price_shop" name="price" class="form-control" value="{{ old('price' , $productDelivery->price) }}" autofocus>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And here is the method for updating data:

```
Route::patch('product-information-pages/free-deliveries/{productDelivery}', 'ShopInformationPagesAdminController@updateProductDelivery')->name('updateProductDelivery')->middleware('permission:static-page-manage');

public function updateProductDelivery(Request $request, ProductDelivery $productDelivery)
    {
        try {
            $data = $request->validate([
                'name' => ['required'],
                'price' => ['required','integer'],
            ]);
            $productDelivery->update($data);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            dd($e);
        }
        return redirect(route('product-information-pages.create'));
    }
```

But now the problem is, data does not be changed and updated somehow and shows this as `dd($e)`:

[image]

So what is going wrong here? How can I fix this issue?

And finally here is the Model `ProductDelivery.php`:

```
class ProductDelivery extends Model
{
    protected $table = "product_deliveries";
}
```

And the table `product_deliveries` looks like this:

[image]

**UPDATE #1**:

Result of `dd($productDelivery->toArray());` goes like this:

```
array:5 [▼
  "id" => 1
  "name" => "Free Delivery"
  "price" => 300000
  "created_at" => "2021-07-04 14:16:09"
  "updated_at" => "2021-07-04 14:16:09"
]
```

Comment: updateProductDelivery doesn't have code to update db .it has only validation code

Comment: @JohnLobo I have added `$productDelivery->update($data);` but still does not update data and show `#message: "The given data was invalid."`

Comment: add protected $guarded = ['id']; in your model

Comment: @JohnLobo I did but still does not update data and shows the message

Comment: @JohnLobo I have also added `protected $fillable = ['price', 'name']; ` but didn't solve the problem!

Comment: first check dd($productDelivery->toArray()) returning that record

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234509/discussion-between-tejoslaeslio-and-john-lobo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is disabled and disabled fields are not submitted with the request.

```html
<input type="text" id="title-shop" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{ old('name' , $productDelivery->name) }}" autofocus>
```

try using `readonly="readonly"` instead of disabled, or omit the field from the request entirely if it should not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a

```
 $productDelivery->update($data);
```

But, how you say to your function what product update? You need first something like

```
$productDelivery = productDelivery::find($id)
$productDelivery->update($data);
```